# World of Warcraft lau addon- move towards player's side

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to create a World of Warcraft addon which allows a player to move towards the side of a player. Just like the follow function but instead of walking behind the player at his side. I was thinking on getting the player's location with `UnitPosition` and make the player walk towards that location by adding:

```
math.cos(direction player is facing in radians)*(length)
math.sin(direction player is facing in radians)*(length)
```

Comment: I think moving via script, if you are able to pull it off even, will cause cows to be made. Any kind of automated movement or casting is considered violation, that's not part of an actual player initiated reaction to something in the game. This kind of thing may be the reason if you aren't getting any responses. That being said you may be able to enable and disable /follow with a slow walk, with respect to distance to a player.  Doing simple compares of dist^2 should be trivial in Lua.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible today using Blizzard's current API.

Player movement addons were possible during the early days of Vanilla.  People made auto-run GPS-style addons to help characters auto-travel on foot from one town to another.